# OpenCL: can I do simultaneous "read" operations?

Tags: opencl

I have an OpenCL buffer created with the read and write flag. Can I access the same memory address simultaneously? say, calling enqueueReadBuffer and a kernel that doesn't modify the contents out-of-order without waitlists, or two calls to kernels that only read from the buffer.

Comment: I think it ultimately depends on the OpenCL driver.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so. Create 2 queues, then call clEnqueieReadBuffer and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel on the different queue.

It ultimately depends on weather the device and driver supports executing different queues at the same time. Most GPUs can while embedded devices may or may not.

Comment: Two command queues aren't needed. I can simply call both clEnqueueReadBuffer and clEnqueueNDRangeKernel on the same queue without asking for synchronization. My question is rather whether there's gonna be a problem when two different processes try to access the same memory address without synchronization flags

Comment: Is a good idea to create 2 queues, since most vendors do not allow concurrent execution of tasks within the queue. But, no,  there will be no issue triggering 2 different processes to read from the same memory.